# Is $n=\Theta(n^{1+o(1)})$?

Tags: asymptotics, landau-notation

Is $n=\Theta(n^{1+o(1)})$?

To me it appears to be true as $n$ tends to infinity $n^{o(1)} =0$.

Comment: Since the situation concerning $\Theta$ is clarified in the answers, let me touch on the last sentence only: $\frac{1}{n}\in o(1)$, but $\sqrt[n]{n} \to 1$, when $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me rephrase the question by getting rid of the double asymptotic notation in the formula: If you are asking whether there **exists** a function $f(n) \in o(1)$ such that $n \in \Theta(n^{1+f(n)})$, then the answer is yes.

Take $f(n) = \frac{1}{\log n}$ and notice that $f(n) \in o(1)$. Then:
$$
n^{1+\frac{1}{\log n}} = n \cdot n^{\frac{1}{\log n}} = n \cdot (2^{\log n})^{\frac{1}{\log n}} = 2n = \Theta(n).
$$

However the same is not true **for all** $f(n) \in o(1)$ as it can be seen by choosing $f(n) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\log n}}$.
$$
n^{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log n}}} = n \cdot n^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log n}}} = n \cdot (2^{\log n})^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log n}}} = n \cdot 2^{\sqrt{\log n}} = \omega(n).
$$

This also shows that, in general, it false that $n^{o(1)}$ approaches $0$. Indeed, $n^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log n}}} = 2^{\sqrt{ \log n}}$ approaches infinity (and grows faster that any polylogarithm).

Answer (score 3):

This amounts to proving

$$1=\Theta(n^{o(1)})=\Theta(e^{\log(n)\,o(1)})$$ (not $0$ as you wrote). But the $o(1)$ factor could decrease to zero slower than $\dfrac1{\log(n)}$.